# Override default headers for an IXMLHTTPRequest2

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to send a HTTP request on Windows 8 using an IXMLHTTPRequest2 object and I want to customise the outgoing Accept-Encoding header to something other than the default value of "gzip, deflate". When I try and use SetRequestHeader method to set the Accept-Encoding header, the method call succeeds but the request is still sent with the default header value instead of the value I provided (Verified by using Wireshark to capture the HTTP request).

Sample code (simplified for beverity):

```
::CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FreeThreadedXMLHTTP60, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS( &m_pXHR ));
m_pXHR->Open( "GET", "http://192.168.0.100/test", m_pXHRCallback.Get(), NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL );
m_pXHR->SetRequestHeader( L"Accept-Encoding", L"gzip" );
m_pXHR->Send( NULL, 0 );
```

Wireshark capture of request that gets made:

```
GET /users/me/id HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Host: 192.168.0.100
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs for SetRequestHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh831168.aspx), it is an append operation only.  You're getting the gzip Accept-Encoding, so I think it's working as intended.  I don't see a way of removing the default header, however.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use IXMLHTTPRequest2::SetProperty() with XHR_PROP_NO_DEFAULT_HEADERS to suppress the default headers.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh831167(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried this 'handle->SetProperty(XHR_PROP_NO_DEFAULT_HEADERS, 1);' but it did not remove Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate from the headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `IXMLHTTPRequest2` API is plainly broken, as it doesn't have a way to remove a header. Or, perhaps, documentation is broken because it doesn't mention that passing an empty string or NULL removes a header.

Also, according to `IXMLHTTPRequest2::SetRequestHeader` declaration:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetRequestHeader(
    /* [ref][string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const WCHAR *pwszHeader,
    /* [unique][string][in] */ __RPC__in_opt_string const WCHAR *pwszValue) = 0;
```

header's value is marked as optional (`__RPC__in_opt_string`) and can be NULL.

So, if you really want to set a header's value, the only proper way that works with `IXMLHTTPRequest2` is to do this:

```
m_pXHR->SetRequestHeader(L"SomeMyHeader", L"");
m_pXHR->SetRequestHeader(L"SomeMyHeader", L"value");
```

This way you can remove, or change some default headers:

```
m_pXHR->SetRequestHeader(L"Accept-Language", L"");
```

Since this isn't documented, this may or may not work for you at some point on some particular version of Windows. If you tried to use `IXMLHTTPRequest2` heavily you'd come to the same conclusion as me: it's just broken crap. This for example doesn't work:

```
m_pXHR->SetRequestHeader(L"Accept-Encoding", L"");
```

Seems that some dude who implemented `IXMLHTTPRequest2` put lots of undocumented logic in there:

- You can complete remove some headers if you set them to NULL or an empty string (for example, `Accept-Language` header, or your own headers can be removed).
- You can change, but not remove some headers (for example, `User-Agent` header).
- You cannot change some headers at all (for example, `Accept-Encoding` header).

When you call ->`Send` on `IXMLHTTPRequest2`, internally they unconditionally set `Accept-Encoding` to whatever they feel like using. That means that you cannot add some alternative encoding like [brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) without resorting to hacks and custom headers.

They should just start using libcurl and expose its API instead of exposing `IXMLHTTPRequest2` shameful quality.